# are question related to app or rom availability and install guide allowed

Tags: discussion, questions

Are questions related to specific custom rom or specific availability to a specific device allowed?
Example: [This question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/179480/225285)
Are questions related to install guides for specific device allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see following your link, the answer is **No:**

> "Questions asking us to **find or recommend an app, device, ROM, accessory or off-site resource** are off-topic for Android Enthusiasts as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam and become obsolete quickly. [Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping)

In this specific case it's even double-off-topic, as it asks for a non-Android ROM (so it's not even Android related).

Answer (score 4):

No. If we took that kind of question, we would end up having to create an index of every device and custom ROM there is. Not only that, we'd have to update it with new versions and to replace dead links. There's no way we can maintain that big a collection of links.

For this reason, such questions are always closed as a duplicate of [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/12442), which has a list of places where you can find ROMs for various devices.